# Sliding door replacements for “non standard” sizes

Tags: doors, replacement, closet

I have a 1962 home with a 72 inch wide x 80 inch tall closet doors as shown in the pics. I am not sure if the sizes are standard.

[image]

These doors are worn out and I was looking for replacements in IKEA but unfortunately they don’t have these sizes. The IKEA door runners are pretty good and with Hettich sliders, springs etc. HomeDepot has the sizes but they look pretty cheap. 
Can some help suggest alternative places to look for options?

More pics:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on the door style. Some closets use bi-fold doors with louvers: http://www.lowes.com/pd_45731-11813-LO45731_1z0s9mjZ1z0s9nt__?productId=4724621&Ns=p_product_price|0&pl=1  ,others that slide: http://www.lowes.com/pd_201629-32998-45006_1z0s9meZ1z0s9nt__?productId=1057659&pl=1 ,and accordion type: http://www.lowes.com/pd_696687-259-WF3680DO_1z0s9mlZ1z0s9nt__?productId=999911281&Ns=p_product_price|1&pl=1 . All the links are for doors measuring 36" w x 80" l.

Comment: This. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction!